# Guice: How do I get an instance of a TypeLiteral-wrapped generic?

Tags: java, guice

I have a generic database access class, which i'm binding using the TypeLiteral construct. Now in a test i want to mock that class and i have therefor created a Provider, that creates a mock instance. In my test, i want to access that mock to define its behaviour.
Now the question is, how can i retrieve the object from the injector?

That's my binding definition:

```
binder.bind(new TypeLiteral<GenericDbClass<Integer>>(){}).GenericDbClassProvider.class);
```

Normally i would get an instance like this:

```
injector.getInstance(GenericDbClass.class);
```

But since i'm not binding the implementation of GenericDbClass to the Interface itself, i don't know how to do that. Do I think to complicated?

Any ideas/help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: As a short term solution i just extended the generic interface with a concrete definition, so i can now get an instance. Still, is there a way to accomplish the task in a more generic way?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use Guice's `Key` facility, which is made for exactly this kind of problem. In your case

```
injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<GenericDbClass<Integer>>(){});
```

will do the trick.

Comment: `injector.getInstance(new Key<GenericDbClass<Integer>>(){})` will also work if you don't need to provide any binding annotation.