# Guice injector.getInstance throwing Configuration exception

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am creating an instance of Predicate using a provider.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("RecordFilters")
public Predicate<ImmutablePair<AbstractRecord, StreamRecord>> getAllFilters() {

    BackfillDataFilter backfillDataFilter = new BackfillDataFilter();
    DummyUpdateFilter dummyUpdateFilter = new DummyUpdateFilter();
    return input -> dummyUpdateFilter.test(input) && backfillDataFilter.test(input);
}
```

When i am trying to get its instance using `injector.getInstance(Predicate.class)` or `injector.getInstance(Key.get(Predicate.class, Names.Named("RecordFilters"))`

I am getting an exception.

```
com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:
  No implementation for java.util.function.Predicate was bound.
  while locating java.util.function.Predicate
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438803/guice-how-do-i-get-an-instance-of-a-typeliteral-wrapped-generic):

```
injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<Predicate<ImmutablePair<AbstractRecord, StreamRecord>>>(){})
```

Comment: This is missing the `Names.named()` part from the OP.  It could be written `new Key<Predicate<ImmutablePair<AbstractRecord, StreamRecord>>>(Names.named("RecordFilters")){}`

Comment: Thanks.
`new Key<Predicate<ImmutablePair<AbstractRecord, StreamRecord>>>(Names.named("RecordFilters")){}`
Works for me.